# How to use curl in a json format

Tags: json, curl

i want to to know to where and how to run a json format like this

```
 curl --request POST \
  --url https://x.com/xxxx \
  --header 'apikey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "filter": {
        "whois_name": "xxxxxxxxx"
    }'
```

Comment: "run a JSON format" makes no sense. You mean you want to know how to run this command or something? You can run it from a command-line where cURL is installed. Whether the data is JSON doesn't seem relevant...

Comment: it is unclear to me what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it from the terminal in a computer which has the `cUrl` utility installed.

Comment: @OussamaEdhibi you can write a shell script (or batch file, in Windows terminology) which contains multiple commands and then execute that. Or you can use any other programming language which is capable of making HTTP requests (which is most if not all of them). I suggest you do some basic research.

Comment: @OussamaEdhibi use a better terminal then, for example, the Cygwin terminal. in those terminals, \ at the end of a line allows you to write a single command with multiple lines. i guess you're using the microsoft windows terminal, `cmd`, ugh